# How java validate certificate

Tags: java, ssl, spring-security, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to call an API using RestTemplte from service on server A and the other service on server B and I get the error below :

```
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
 sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target; nested exception is
 javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
 sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

The problem remains, even when I add the configuration (code below) into the REST-template.

```
SSLContext sslContext = new SSLContextBuilder()
    .loadTrustMaterial(new File(keystore), trustStorePassword.toCharArray())
    .build();
SSLConnectionSocketFactory socketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext);
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
    .setSSLSocketFactory(socketFactory)
    .build();
HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(factory);
```

The solution that I found on the net is to export a certificate from chrome and add it to the JVM trusted certificate. I don't know if this is the right solution because we can change this certificate every three months, for example.

And I have some other questions :

- Does JVM knows all certificate authority (i think there are billion..), for example, when I call google using rest certificate will be validated by JVM using "security/cacerts"?
- Should I add our certificate in JVM trusted certifies to fix `sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target`?
- The validation process is not automatic by SSL mechanism?

Comment: What do you mean by _internal Certificate authority_? Client certificate should not be added to trusted on server side, but all certificates from client certification path must or at least root certificate if all other certs are included into request.

Comment: thanks @art by internal i mean a certificate generated by our client and i its used in intranet. i added some detail in my post.

Comment: The JVM has a truststore with CA that it trusts. If you have a custom CA you want to trust you have to adjust the truststore your JVM (or your REST client) is using.

Comment: I have a keystore file in our server I don't know if possible to configure using the Java code JVM to include that file in their references.